# Ignore errors and warnings for a VIM plugin

Tags: vim, runtime-error, vim-plugin

Suppose I have a VIM plugin that is very useful, but it generates a lot of errors/warnings that I don't care for.

How can I ignore all errors from that plugin? I just want to be disturbed by these messages anymore.

Is there any setting/function call that turns off such things?

I know that the best thing would be to report this as issue, but how can I just make them not appear?

Example of errors:

> [image]

Comment: Why don't you name the plugin, and include some sample errors?!

Comment: @IngoKarkat I can do that, but I was asking for the general case.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Well, I would definitely look into the root cause of the errors, as it might affect the plugin's functionality. At least this should allow you to send a precise bug report to the plugin's author.

Errors and warnings can be suppressed via the `:silent!` (note the `!`) command. Basically, any Ex command can be prefixed with it. So, if you have a `:TroublesomeCommand`, you can silence the errors via

```
:silent! TroublesomeCommand
```

To silence the plugin (if you really must), you can might be able to redefine its mappings (to include `:silent!`) and commands, but the use of `<SID>` may force you to modify the plugin itself. In that case, you can also put the `:silent!` directly before the offending command (the error should include its location), but again, fixing the root cause would be preferable.

Comment: I tried `:silent!` but it doesn't work for me. See screenshot from question. Thanks!

Comment: @IonicăBizău: The screenshot shows autocmds. For those the `:silent!` needs to be placed before the right-hand command definition. If you just prepend it before `:autocmd` (or any custom call that defines those), it'll only silence errors during the autocmd _definition_. Again, rather fix the root cause, please!

Comment: @IngoKarkat You really have a knack for clearly explaining concepts.  I love the "TroublesomeCommand" name you used!